# Programmatically get list of Portlets deployed in Liferay 7.2

Tags: osgi, portlet, liferay-7, liferay-7.2, liferay-7.3

I want to create a custom widgets tab where I want to display a list for available portlets. Is there any way to find out the list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an easy answer, but there should be enough information in source code for the MarketplaceAppManager portlet that is used in the Control Panel App Manager to list the apps (bundles).

I looked at the portlet code and I think a good starting place would be the JSPs for that portlet:
/modules/apps/marketplace/marketplace-app-manager-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources.  Specifically view_modules.jsp seems to be what is responsible for rendering the list.

Looking at these would give you a good idea of what is involved with fetching and displaying them, and a hint at what the level of effort might be to emulate it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro. I will definitely have a look into this.